# DateTime in roslyn CSharpScript returns 'expecting ;'

Tags: c#, roslyn, csharpscript

Use of DateTime within the roslyn CSharpScript evaluator returns error code 'Expected ;' while strings work fine.

Using Visual Studio 2019 with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting 3.3.1

Understanding that the evaluator requires configuration, added DateTime assembly along with the custom class assembly.

```
public class Install
    {
        public int InstallId { get; set; }
        public int RegistrationId { get; set; }
        public int EnvironmentId { get; set; }
        public DateTime SubmitDateTime { get; set; }
        public string SubmitIdentity { get; set; }
        public DateTime TargetDateTime { get; set; }
        public string InstallerIdentity { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StopDateTime { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

```
string queryText;
var fooFuture = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
var fooPast = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);

switch (TimeFrame)
  {
    case "future":  // fails (expected) //
       queryText = $"i => i.TargetDateTime < fooFuture";
       break;
    case "current":  // works //
       queryText = "i => i.Status == \"In Progress\"";
       break;
    case "past":   // fails with interpolation -- expecting ; //
       queryText = $"i => i.TargetDateTime > {fooPast}";
       break;
    default:      // fails with DateTime -- expecting ; //
       queryText = $"i => i.TargetDateTime < {DateTime.Now.AddDays(15)} && i.TargetDateTime > {DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15)}";
       break;
   }

ScriptOptions options = ScriptOptions.Default
  .AddReferences(typeof(Install).Assembly)
  .AddReferences(typeof(System.DateTime).Assembly);

Func<Install, bool> queryTextExpression = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<Install, bool>>(queryText, options);
```

Cannot understand here why a basic DateTime object causes issues.

String resolves to `"i => i.TargetDateTime > 10/25/2019 11:00:00 AM"`. Wrapping in quotes causes it to be interpreted as string.

*EDIT*: I should add that hard-coding the string to the example above also fails with same error message, leading me to believe it is a parsing issue? It's not sure how to handle the characters within a DateTime object?

Comment: Why the down-vote? Really, please provide an explanation so that I can better draft questions in the future. Don't just down-arrow and bolt. How does that help?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen here? You're using *string* interpolation, which calls `ToString()` on the objects passed into it. In the case of `DateTime` you get a date string, as you have seen.

Comment: @Herohtar - that doesn't make it a bad question.  Hover over the upvote/downvote button to read the tooltip.  Does this question meet the criteria of showing research, being clear, and useful?  I think it does.

Comment: I would expect the cause of this problem would be readily apparent in the debugger if you inspect the value `queryText` gets in each case.  I didn't downvote, but I can see someone saw this question and thought "he didn't try debugging it."

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint The question is essentially "why does evaluating `i.TargetDateTime > 10/25/2019 11:00:00 AM` result in an error?". How is that a good question? It's clearly not a valid C# statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as you said - the string is resolving to `"i => i.TargetDateTime > 10/25/2019 11:00:00 AM"` which is not valid C# code.  Even if you added quotes, you can't directly compare a `DateTime` to a `string`

Ultimately, you either need to be comparing objects of the same type.  Either `string` to `string`, `DateTime` to `DateTime`, `long` to `long`, etc.  I prefer to keep them as `DateTime` objects.

Thus, you need to construct a `DateTime` on the right-hand side of the expression.

One way would be to use the `DateTime` constructor, like this:

```
queryText = $"i => i.TargetDateTime > new System.DateTime({fooPast.Ticks}, System.DateTimeKind.{fooPast.Kind})";
```

Another, arguably cleaner mechanism would be through the built-in binary serialization methods, which take both `Ticks` and `Kind` into account in a single value:

```
queryText = $"i => i.TargetDateTime > System.DateTime.FromBinary({fooPast.ToBinary()})";
```

Comment: I tried the Binary solution posted by Matt:

{"(1,45): error CS0426: The type name 'FromBinary' does not exist in the type 'DateTime'"}

Will try the first variation. Thanks.

Comment: @Badchenn What platform are you using?  .Net Framework?  .Net Core?  .Net Standard?  And what version?  That method does exist.

Comment: Indeed - [and exists in every version of every framework](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.DateTime.FromBinary(Int64))

Comment: DOTNETCORE 3.0

OK. Found that calling .ToBinary within the string was not acceptable. However, I easily called it on the variable declaration above. So the variable fooPast is not a binary.

But, compilation failed again:

  queryText "i => i.Status \"Complete\" && i.TargetDateTime > new System.DateTime.FromBinary(-8586301823432291125)"


ERROR: +  ex {"(1,15): error CS1002: ; expected"} Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CompilationErrorException

Comment: @Badchenn `i.Status \"Complete\"`  doesn't look like valid C# code to me.

Comment: That did it. I ended up using the very slick Binary option. Missed the subtle lack of 'new' on the binary solution (compared to the Ticks solution).

Working as expected. Thanks a ton Matt!

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint 